# Order of elements in group cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology

OK, I'm just learning about cohomology of groups, and I want to make sure I'm not missing anything in this question:

> Let $n$ be an abelian group, let $G$ be a group, let $\tau$ be an
>   action of $G$ on $N$ by automorphisms, and let $n>0$ be an integer.
>   Prove that if every element of $N$ has finite order dividing an
>   integer $m$, then every member of $H^n(G,N)$ has finite order dividing
>   $m$.

To my mind, every element of $H^n(G,N)$ is an $N$-valued function (mod $B^n$, and belonging to $Z^n$). So if $m \cdot \nu = 0$ for all $\nu \in N$, then certainly $(g_1, \dotsc, g_n) \mapsto m \cdot f(g_1, \dotsc, g_n)$ is the zero function...right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Small typo: I think you mean "dividing $m$" not "defining $m$".

Comment: That has now been answered by the person who posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not missing anything, seeing $H^n(G,N)$ through the inhomogenous cochain (i.e. functions from $G^n$ to $N$ verifying some equations mod $B^n$) allows you to make this proof.

A far more intersting result is the following : if $G$ is a group of finite order and $n>0$ then any $f\in Z^n(G,N)$ verifies that $|G|.f\in B^n(G,N)$ so that every element of $H^n(G,N)$ has finite order dividing $|G|$.

Hint : given $f\in Z^n(G,N)$ we set :

$$\nu(g_1,...,g_{n-1}):=\sum_{g\in G}f(g_1,...,g_{n-1},g) $$

And then compute :

$$\partial^{n-1}(\nu)(g_1,...,g_n) ...$$

I leave the (heavy) calculation to you and juste remark that if $|G|$ is finite and mutliplication by $|G|$ is a bijection in $N$ then you will have that $H^n(G,N)=0$ if $n>0$. In particular, this is true if $N$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-vectorial space. So it gives easily a cancellation of group cohomology (which appears to be a good one, it applies sometimes).

Comment: Let me ask: when we try to determine $H^2(G,N)$ via a factor set $a: G^2 \to N$, are we always free to take $a(1_G, 1_G)=1_N$, or could we be missing some possibilities that way?

Comment: Yes, to be a little more general for each $n\geq 1$, $f\in Z^n(G,N)$, you can find $f_0\in Z^n(G,N)$ such that $f_0(1_G,...,1_G)=1_N$. When $n$ is odd it is because each $n$-cocycle verifies this and when $n$ is even, if $a:=f(1_G,...,1_G)$ then set $\nu:=a$ the constant function from $G^{n-1}$ to $N$, you easily get that $f_0:=f-\partial^{n-1}(\nu)$ is what you want. By the way such cocycles are called normalized cocycles.

Comment: Does this assume $N$ abelian?

Comment: Well, it seems a little hard to make group cohomology with non commutative coefficients, in what I wrote $N$ is abelian. In this paper "computing galois cohomology and forms of linear algebraic groups" Sergei Haller defined the $H^1(G,N)$ when $N$ is non commutative as a generalisation of the abelian case. But it is just a pointed set and you cannot do the same for $H^2$...